# How to drop a row in a JSON file with invalid format

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm currently working on a scala job that will ingest the data from JSON file to Hive tables, but I did encounter some files that have a row/entry with invalid format. Here's the example:

```
[{"name":"John", "age":30, "address":"15 yemen road Yemen"},
{"name":"John", "age":30, "address":"",15 yemen road Yemen"}]
```

The address on the second entry is what causes the failure and the idea is to just drop that row. I already tried adding `DROPMALFORMED` mode but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to remove the square brackets and turn your input into NLJSON format: one JSON object per line.

```
{"name":"John", "age":30, "address":"15 yemen road Yemen"}
{"name":"John", "age":30, "address":"",15 yemen road Yemen"}
```

With that input, the Spark setting DROPMALFORMED would remove the bad *line*, whereas now it will remove the whole array.

Cf. [Spark DataFrameReader](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#json(java.lang.String...))

> "Loads a JSON file (one object per line) and returns the result as a DataFrame"